# If Element not working for code

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have a function below that is supposed to check if the array contains the letter X or O in a certain position. I made it so if X or O does not exist in that element that it will insert the X or O into that element. But for some reason it is not working. If say X is in the element and its O turn to put it in it just puts in O and doesnt tell me that the move was already made.

Maybe i messed up my design here?

```
void makeMove()
{
    if ( choosePositionX )
    {
        if (ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'X' || ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'O' )
        {
            ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] = 'X';
        }
        else
            cout << "Player O has already made this move" << endl << endl;
    }


    if ( choosePositionO )
    {
        if (ticTacBoard[choosePositionO - 1] != 'X' || ticTacBoard[choosePositionO - 1] != 'O' )
        {
            ticTacBoard[choosePositionO - 1] = 'O';
        }
        else
            cout << "Player X has already made this move" << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i actually fixed it let me check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should'nt this be && instead of ||

because in this case, the if condition will always return true.

If you want that both of the conditions must be true, then use '&&' But I guess that you are taking OR to the literal meaning, If you want that only One of the given condition must be true than use the following expression

If you want to achieve, Either One of Both condition is true, then basically you are trying XOR operation, that could be achieved like this

```
if ((ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'X'  ||  ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'O' )
  && ! (ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'X'  &&  ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'O' ))
```

the above condition will make sure, that only one of them is TRUE. `either` X or O

have not tested the condition, pardon any bugs, thats an idea

Comment: I thought || meant or meaning if either X or O is there not both?

Comment: || means, If any one of them is true, it will return true. is this what you want ?

Comment: I want it so if either X or O is in there to return that. Because the element will either have X or O

Comment: @mystycs if u want any one of this condition to be true, plz see the above edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Whatever value it has, it is always going to be either not X or not O. You check if it is not-X OR not-O. That test will always be true.

You want to check if it *is* X or *is* O. In that case, the move is already taken. Change:

```
    if (ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'X' || ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'O' )
    {
        ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] = 'X';
    }
    else
        cout << "Player O has already made this move" << endl << endl;
```

to

```
    if (ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'X' && ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] != 'O' )
    {
        ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] = 'X';
    }
    else
        cout << "Player " << ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] << " has already made this move" << endl << endl;
```

If the player made the move successfully, you need to change which player goes next. If not, you need to let the same player try again.

Comment: That's your first and biggest mistake, sure. Clearly, whatever the value is, it will always not be X or not be O. So your 'if' is always true.